# API to monitor iphone app store reviews

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to develop a review monitoring system for several iPhone apps I've developed, for instance to email me with the contents of a review when one comes in.  (Right now, without an iPhone, I can't even view reviews.) I was hoping there was some online browser for the app store (like cyrket for android), but I am unsure if this exists (I can't find any definitive answer via searching).

Is there any online browser that can be scraped? Or is there at least some API I can use to view app reviews?  Or will it come down to sniffing packets and reverse engineering the app store protocol?

Comment: can't you just use iTunes? The app store is available there as well.

Comment: Is there a linux client? Apple doesn't seem to provide one.

Answer (score 84):

Unfortunately, none of the answers here did the trick, and  I didn't get the feedback I needed.

However, I found an answer.

One can just go to the rss feed from Apple feedback (in the itunes connect site and replace the word xml with json (for those [like me] who prefer to work with json objects). However note, that XML has 2 extra fields, that are missing in JSON : `<updated>`(very useful) and `<content type="html">`.

https://itunes.apple.com/HERE-YOU-PUT-THE-CONTRY-CODE/rss/customerreviews/id=PUT-APP-ID-HERE/sortBy=mostRecent/json
APP ID - you cant get your app id from itunsconnect in the view details tab.
country codes - like il for israel, it for italy and etc.

For example, in my case the link was -

https://itunes.apple.com/il/rss/customerreviews/id=567630281/sortBy=mostRecent/xml

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you change add 'json' instead of 'xml' it retrieves the reviews using that format.

Comment: It seems the above would only give feedback which has title and comment. How to access those star ratings without title and/or comment?

Comment: cant find the review's date, any idea how can i get it?

Comment: With the same address?

Comment: For some reason, when I try that URL (and others with IDs that I'm trying to use), I'm just getting some boilerplate responses with author, title, rights, updated, icon, etc, but I'm not getting actual review data. Do I need to be signed into anything in order to get it?

Comment: thanks, it work...and how can i get like google play store app review..? any suggestion pls

Comment: The url returns only 50 latest reviews. Any idea how to get more?

Comment: This is useful even after several years. thanks!

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim how did you get all the reviews (rather than just the most recent 50)?

Comment: @HuwDavies: See my gist https://gist.github.com/MNF/4cd1fd31d6f49e5fe49530b683985d14 and corresponding comment

Comment: is there any possible way to get resent reviews from all countries ?

Comment: I just run a loop on al the countries code (if you want I can copy the list and post it).

Comment: I desperately require all the user reviews of an app. Nort justs the first 50. Any idea?

Comment: u can use the pagination info provided in the xml to get 500 reviews. Don't know how to go beyond that.

Comment: @AnilPBabu How to get 500 reviews pls provide the format or example

Comment: @saravanansaminathan in this link https://itunes.apple.com/il/rss/customerreviews/id=567630281/sortBy=mostRecent/xml there is json object like this - {"attributes":{"rel":"next", "href":""}}.Eventhough this link doesnt have,  href will contain the link to the next set of values. U cn get upto 500 comments. I had got it. i dont have that working link of mine with me now.

Comment: Works even in 2022. 

Facebook reviews: https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/page=1/id=284882215/sortby=mostrecent/json

@MichaelFreidgeim Change the `page` param's value for paginated results.

Answer (score 14):

I know this question is probably out of date, but I found an EXCELLENT resource http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/09/10/useful-itunes-web-services outlining the various APIs that are available for querying iTunes data, INCLUDING a mechanism for querying app reviews, e.g.
https://itunes.apple.com/rss/customerreviews/id=400274934/xml

Answer (score 5):

We had the same issues, and since we have 7 apps in the App Store, visiting the store pages wasn't really an option. So we built a tool that we recently released that you might find useful: https://launchkit.io/reviews/

It emails you all new reviews and posts them to your teams Slack channel.

Comment: Hi @Brenden, I tried your app, it's pretty awesome and simple! But can you tell me if you support tracking reviews from all around the world, or just US? I'm not sure - maybe my account is still collecting data from Apple, but for now I have only reviews from States...

Comment: I see: "International reviews coming soon", cool, is it still a vital promise :)?

Comment: Does this get both Android and iOS or just iOS app store reviews?

Comment: Superb stuff, would pay for it!!!! Especially for the Google Play support

Answer (score 3):

This post outlines building such a "scraper" using curl.  It also gathers international reviews, which is difficult to do just using iTunes:

http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/08/scraping-appstore-reviews.html