# iOS: Access the number of App Store reviews current version

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

**My question: What API is used to access the number of reviews for the current app version from the App Store?**

I've seen this in a few apps, including Overcast (screenshot below)

[image: app screenshot]

I haven't made the jump to Swift yet, so objective C please!

I haven't been able to find the answer in documentation or via a search. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Customer reviews are part of the iTunes API. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20305144/22147

Comment: To get and grab that much XML/RSS data will make setting page loading take a long time. I wonder if overcast is using some sort of backend grab i.e. they are grabbing a text file from there own server which contains only a number like 91 reviews etc. The actual processing of that file perhaps is done on their server once nightly. Just a hunch.

Comment: @SamB perhaps but it seems the API returns a JSON object. It can't be that heavy to download. I'll probably use GCD to load it asynchronously - I'll post the code for it when I'm done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use iTunes Search API:
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=*Your_App_9Digit_ID*. 
The result is a JSON doc. You can parse it
and use *userRatingCount* field for your purpose.
Here is the link to the full documentation of the search API:  http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Comment: How can I access individual reviews instead of count?

Comment: of note -- this may have changed or perhaps the userRatingCount and other fields do not appear until a threshold has been reached. So for an app with few reviews, this field may be not populated in the returned JSON doc.