# Reading reviews from Appstore iOS

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Is it possible to read reviews from App Store ?
I mean like i want to read the ratings and reviews of the App from the App store,
through code(objective c/ swift)

If yes then how ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can read the reviews of your app through iTunes Connect.

1. Login to your [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) account;
2. Click on **My Apps**;
3. Click on your app;
4. Click on Activity (Should be next to TestFlight);
5. Click on **Ratings and Reviews**.

Enjoy reading your reviews. I hope this helped!

Comment: @SaurabhBisht Are you trying to get your app reviews on the App Store through code to show in your app?

Comment: @SaurabhBisht Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090282/api-to-monitor-iphone-app-store-reviews)? See the most up-voted answer.