# How to get all reviews of an App from Apple AppStore?

Tags: ios, api, app-store, itunes

I have a different situation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20305144/3929188)

The answer there has an URL to get the recent 50 reviews.

But, I would like to read all the reviews for a certain time period.

The code [here](https://gist.github.com/MNF/4cd1fd31d6f49e5fe49530b683985d14) says it will do the trick, but it doesn't even compile for me. I don't have a clue what is Microsoft.SDC package.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Through research, I found out that we could get 500 latest reviews from the URL given above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API to monitor iphone app store reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090282/api-to-monitor-iphone-app-store-reviews)

Comment: @Yuu Dear brother, I have linked an answer to this "original question" in this question which I have posted. Please read my question carefully. I have a different requirement