# React Native: Display your App Store rating in app? (iOS/Android)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I hope you are well.

**What I want to do**: I am looking for some kind of library that can show your App store rating in app. If I am able to get it for android that's a bonus.

At the moment I have been unsuccessful in finding anything that does this, is anyone aware of one that could do this?

If you know a way of doing this yourself please let me know!

**Example**: The example below what kind of simplistic design I am looking for for the rating, with the stars and a decimal rating.

[image: A screenshot of my idea]

Comment: You'll most likely have to use `fetch` yourself to get the reviews from web services. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090282/api-to-monitor-iphone-app-store-reviews) might be helpful for iOS but it seems a little outdated. Try searching for web APIs for Android/iOS